# How to Convert using of SQLite to Simple SQL command in C#

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlite

I want to get start with DayPilot control
I do not use SQLite and this control documented based on SQLite.

I want to use SQL instead of SQLite so if you can, please do this for me.

main site with samples       http://www.daypilot.org/calendar-tutorial.html

The database contains a single table with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE event (  id VARCHAR(50),  name VARCHAR(50),  eventstart DATETIME,  eventend DATETIME);
```

Loading Events

```
  private DataTable dbGetEvents(DateTime start, int days)    {
     SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT [id], [name], [eventstart], [eventend] FROM [event] WHERE NOT (([eventend] <= @start) OR ([eventstart] >= @end))", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("start", start);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("end", start.AddDays(days));
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
  }
```

Update

```
  private void dbUpdateEvent(string id, DateTime start, DateTime end)    {
    using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE [event] SET [eventstart] = @start, [eventend] = @end WHERE [id] = @id", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("start", start);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("end", end);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create your db in sql server, after that you only need to change `SQLiteCommand` to `SQLCommand`. you don't need to change anything except connection string info.

Comment: I'd change connction string to my new SQL server database ( and this is not the answer ) I want to convert this part of sql lite code into t-sql

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
private void dbUpdateEvent(string id, DateTime start, DateTime end)    {
using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString))
   {
    con.Open();
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE [event] SET [eventstart] = @start, [eventend] = @end WHERE [id] = @id", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("start", start);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("end", end);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

You should be able to use

```
private void dbUpdateEvent(string id, DateTime start, DateTime end)    {
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString))
   {
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [event] SET [eventstart] = @start, [eventend] = @end WHERE [id] = @id", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("start", start);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("end", end);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

You also need to add; a project reference to System.Data and `using System.Data.SqlClient` at the top of the class.